# Problems writing log to a shared docker volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, log4j2, promtail

I have not been able to connect the containers of my app and promtail via volumes so that promtail can read it.

I have an app that creates log files (by log4j2 in java ) to a folder with the extension appXX.log, when I share volumes my app is not able to write this file.

Here is my docker-compose (I have skipped the loki/grafana containers).

My app writes fine in that path without the shared volume, so it must be somehow how docker manages the volumes. Any ideas what could be going on?

```
   promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:2.4.1
    volumes:
      - "app-volume:/var/log/"
      - "path/config.yml:/etc/promtail/config.yml"
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/config.yml

   app:
    image: app/:latest
    volumes:
      - "app-volume:/opt/app/logs/"
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c","java $${JAVA_ARGS} -jar app-*.jar"]

volumes:
     app-volume:
```

On the other hand, I do not know if it is the correct way to log an application to promtail, I have seen that usually read directly the log of the container (which does not work for me, because it only works in docker-linux) and I can think of these other possibilities What would be the right one in case it is impossible by volumes?

[other alternatives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNfYE.png)

Any idea is welcome, thanks !

Comment: What's the specific problem you're running into?  Are the two containers running as root or as some other user(s)?  I'd generally recommend logging to stdout, not a file, where the logs can be picked up by `docker logs`.  You seem to acknowledge this approach in your last paragraph; what problems do you run into if you try this?  (You don't mention your host OS, but I'd expect the native-Linux approach to also work on Docker Desktop for Mac and on VM-based solutions, no specific experience with Windows.)

Comment: Both containers should run as root if . The problem comes when linking the volumes, that promtail's volume "overwrites" my application's volume, and promtail is unable to write. I was referring to directly using docker drivers (which is not supported on windows) https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/docker-driver/ . Read directly from docker stdout I haven't tried it yet.Would I need to run as sudo my promtail container to be able to see the stdout of the containers ? or it is not necessary to get up all with the same user in the docker-compose ?